# Sava data in a mobile flash application

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I want to ask what is the best way to save some data for an educational mobile app I want to create with flash. Is it

- shared objects or
- XML file?

I want to save data like

- username,
- wrong / correct attempts,
- time to complete
- etc.

I don't want the app to ask the child where to save the file.
Also I want - each time the child use the app - the new data to append to the old data.
A link to a tutorial would be very useful.

Comment: **SharedObject**. You should check it, but I think Mobile AIR does not need any permissions at all in order to use **SharedObject** as much as you want.

Comment: FYI, I flagged this question as off-topic because it's purely opinion-based, so it isn't a good fit for the Q&A-format of stackoverflow.

Comment: Did you get this figured out?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care if the saved info is human readable (or prefer it that way), a good way to do this is to use serialized objects in either a save file, or a shared object.

The process is pretty similar regardless of which storage mechanism used.  Here is an example.

First, make a global var for your shared object (probably at the start of your application):

```
    var sharedObj:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("MySaveData");

    //if data exists in the shared object, load it or do something with it
    if(sharedObj.data.userName){
        trace("Hello " + saveData.userName);
    }
```

Later, when you want to save some data:

```
    sharedObj.data.userName = "fflinstone";
    sharedObj.data.wrongAttempts = 5;
    //etc for other properties you want to add

    sharedObj.flush(); //write the data to file
```

> Keep in mind, that any non-primitive class you use, must be registered to unserialize them.

So, if you wanted to save a type of object that required an import statement (like a `Rectangle` for instance) you'd have to register that by doing:

```
flash.net.registerClassAlias("flash.geom.Rectangle", Rectangle);  //you only have to have this once in your whole application, usually at the start of your program
```

---

Alternatively, you could create a model for your save data (a custom class).

To do it that way, create a new class file (in AnimateCC, go `file -> new -> actionscript 3.0 class`- Give it the name `SaveData`).  Make the content of the file look like this:

```
    package {
        public class SaveData {
            public var userName:String;
            public var wrongAttempts:int;
            public var correctAttempts:int;
            public var timeToCompletion:Number;
        }
    }
```

Add whatever properties you want to store as public vars as shown.

Then, register the class so it can saved in a shared object (you can do this at the start of your app)

```
flash.net.registerClassAlias("SaveData",SaveData);
```

Then create a global save data variable:

```
var saveData:SaveData;
```

And load in the data:

```
saveData = sharedObject.data.saveData as SaveData;
if(saveData){
    //load your saved data
}else{
    saveData = new SaveData();//create a new one since one didn't previously exist
}
```

During you app, assign values to the save data object:

```
saveData.wrongAttempts++;
```

Then later save it:

```
sharedObject.data.saveData = saveData;
sharedObject.flush();
```

Comment: Here are some similar answers I've given that show other methods:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667848/as3-for-ios-how-to-serialize-an-array-and-then-save-it/15668079#15668079

Comment: This one shows writing a file (instead of shared object) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33422242/how-do-i-serialize-vector-customobject/33455756#33455756

Comment: Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125221/using-file-to-save-scene-object-locations-to-rebuild-later-in-as3/30131304#30131304

Answer (score 1):

well one way is to have a sqlite database inside your Air app but it needs sql coding skills .
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a5497-7fb4.html

Comment: Now please defend why storing a couple of strings and numbers not only needs SQL database, but also is "the best way".